# Which MS product for Online file system with hierarchical group file permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

I would like to know which is the correct MS service offering to get the following features:

- Online files storage with hierarchical file system permissions (role
  based?). ie having folders that only certain groups of people can access, ability to manage group membership,...
- Excel online

I was looking at:

- Sharepoint Online
- Office 365
- One Drive for Business

What is the minimum set of services I need to get to have the described features.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online delivers the powerful features of SharePoint without the associated overhead of managing the infrastructure on your own. Flexible management options ensure that you still retain the control you need to meet the compliance requirements of your organization. You can purchase SharePoint in the cloud as a standalone offering or as part of an Office 365 suite, where you can also get access to Exchange, Lync, the Office clients, and web apps.

SO if you dont need the exchange / Lync / OWA, then i think your best bet is SharePoint Online. As per your requirement, you need the Excel Services then **SharePoint Online P2** will be best fit. This will give you everything you mentioned.

http://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/compare-sharepoint-plans